# What is the interpretation of Zechariah Chapter 3?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, beis-hamikdash, prophecies, menorah--in-temple, zecharia-book-of

In Zechariah 3, there's a vision of Joshua the High Priest.  Satan is accusing him, and then Satan is rebuked.  Joshua is then found to be standing before the altar in filthy garments, which are then removed and replaced with clean garments.  This is followed by the angel of the LORD talking about several other things, like the Branch, and an engraved stone with seven eyes, etc. What is the interpretation of this?

My apologies if this is too broad of a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see [Rashi's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) commentary to the chapter in English [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/showrashi/true/aid/16207/jewish/Chapter-3.htm). Joshua was being accused because his sons had married to gentile women and he did not interfere. This was symbolized by the filthy garments which were then removed and replaced with clean ones, alluding that his sons should separate from their wives, and he would be forgiven and the sins would be replaced with merits.